# Null value in DataTable

Tags: ado.net

I am quite surprised how come the following code is working without getting a NullReferenceException exception?

```cs
table.Rows[0][1] = null;
Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```

Could anybody explain?

Comment: Have you tried it with a simpler case? `object foo = null; Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the item will actually be set to an instance of [System.DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) rather than `null`.

Comment: This coercion only works one way (null -> DBNull): care must be used when accessing "null" values from a DataTable for this very reason.